# How to localize validation error messages for deeply nested attributes in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

In my Ruby on Rails 7 app I have a `Booking` which has many `CargoItems` which in turn can have many `CargoItemDocuments` (which basically just contains an `upload` attachment).

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :cargo_items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cargo_items

end
```

---

```
class CargoItem < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :booking

  has_many :cargo_item_documents

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cargo_item_documents

end
```

---

```
class CargoItemDocument < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :cargo_item

  has_one_attached :upload

end
```

Unfortunately, the localized validation messages for the deeply nested `CargoItemDocuments` aren't rendered correctly. This is my German localization file:

```
de:
  activerecord: 
    attributes: 
      booking:
        number: "Nummer"
        date: "Datum"
      cargo_item: 
        title: "Titel"
        weight: "Gewicht"
        cargo_item_documents:
          upload: "Datei" # <-- Not working!
```

So when upload an invalid file type, instead of a German validation error message I am currently getting:

> Cargo items cargo item documents upload hat einen ungültigen Dateityp

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Just for kicks, have you tried moving `cargo_item_documents` to the top level/under `attributes`? If your `cargo_item` is working even though a booking `accepts_nested_attributes_for` cargo items, the same should work for `cargo_item_documents`.

Comment: @DennisHackethal, I just tried that (in both singular and plural form) but to no avail.

Comment: What error key do you want to use? There is no one in your YAML

Comment: Have you tried adding the translation under `cargo_item/cargo_item_documents`? (Not sure whether it should be plural or singular) Here they use in that form (`user/role`): https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models

Comment: @David: Yes, that's what I tried at the very beginning, after reading through the Rails documentation. But it's not working for me, neither in singular nor in plural form (tried all possible combinations).

Comment: Never done this myself, but the `has_one_attached :upload` actually creates a `has_one :upload_attachment` association, makes sense that that might be what you need to declare in your i18n YAML.

Comment: @smathy: Thanks but I could not get this to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, three weeks later this turns out to be the solution:

```
de:
  activerecord: 
    attributes: 
      booking:
        number: "Nummer"
        date: "Datum"
      cargo_item: 
        title: "Titel"
        weight: "Gewicht"
      cargo_items/cargo_item_documents:
        upload: "Datei"
```